# Creating winword from ACUCOBOL using OLE object definitions

Tags: ole, acucobol-gt

I'm pretty new to COBOL and programming and I'm having problems to create a word document from COBOL using ole object definitions.

I cant really find a good documentation for it, just some vba examples.
I got some stuff to work - creating the document, writing text, formatting the text.
Now I'm trying to add a header with an image to it - I found some vba code which I'm trying to translate:

```vb
With ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers _  .Item(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range.InsertBefore "Sales Report"
```

I don't really understand it, because "headers" is not a property of sections, and also I never learned vba...

I'm using microfocus acubench 10.2.1

Current code:

```
       working-storage section.
       77  hFileSystemObject           handle of FileSystemObject.
       01  word-handles.                                                                                  
           03 wrdApp handle of Application of word.
           03 wrdDoc handle of Document of word.
           03 sections handle of section of word.
           03 myHeaderFooter handle of  WdHeaderFooterIndex of word.
       procedure division.
       word-testing-section.                 
       word-testing-010.                  
           CREATE  Application OF Word HANDLE IN WrdApp.
           MODIFY  WrdApp Documents::Add() GIVING wrdDoc.
           MODIFY  WrdApp            @Visible = 1.
           modify wrddoc @range = (0,100).
           modify wrddoc @sections ::add() giving headersection.
           modify wrddoc @sections(1)::@headers::
           @item(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage)::@range::@insertbefore = 
           "Sales Report".
```

leads to:

```
D:\AcuReal\Source\testing2.cbl, line 52: Wrong number of parameters: 0 expected, 1 found
D:\AcuReal\Source\testing2.cbl, line 52: '@HEADERS' is not a property or method of 'CLASS @SECTIONS'
D:\AcuReal\Source\testing2.cbl, line 52: 'SECTIONS' must be a 'put' property or method of '@SECTIONS'
D:\AcuReal\Source\testing2.cbl, line 52: Undefined data item: @HEADERS
D:\AcuReal\Source\testing2.cbl, line 52: Verb expected, :: found
```

i also tried

```
modify WRDdoc @sections::@item(1)::
@headers::@item(@wdHeaderFooterPrimary)::@range::insertbefore"test".

D:\AcuReal\Source\testing2.cbl, line 60: Wrong number of parameters: 0 expected, 1 found
D:\AcuReal\Source\testing2.cbl, line 60: Wrong number of parameters: 0 expected, 1 found
```

and if i delete the parameters

```
D:\AcuReal\Source\testing2.cbl, line 58: Wrong number of parameters: 1 expected, 0 found
D:\AcuReal\Source\testing2.cbl, line 60: Wrong number of parameters: 1 expected, 0 found
```

Im pretty sure i have to use item twice with the wdHeaderFooterFirstPage parameter, but i have no idea why i get "wrong number of parameters"
Really frustrating

```
How can I create a word document from COBOL using ole object definitions?
```

Comment: Hi thank you, I've edited my question again, hopefully in the right way.